# Django Crispy Forms - Layout Helper - Set Div Id

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

like the `css_class` attribute I can pass to a `` `Div() `` in the layout helper, I need to set the `id` as well...

```
 self.helper.layout = Layout(              
            Div('attr1', css_class="myclass")
         )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, per try-and-error I found the solution! I think its hard to find via Google...

You can use `css_id`:

```
 self.helper.layout = Layout(              
            Div('attr1', css_class="myclass", css_id="myid")
         )
```

Comment: It is [documented](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/layouts.html)

Comment: @AamirAdnan: Well... for some reason Google doesnt give a good answer and searching in most of the docs also didn't bring a result. So I thought maybe I can help people like me... :)